# for loops executed 3 times where it should be just once

Tags: java, for-loop

I just started learning coding (Java) for days and I found this problem.

It is a very simple for loops program where the loops will stop executed after the user input an 'S' on the keyboard. It works fine, but if I put the wrong input the loops executed 3 times instead of just once.

```
class ForTest   {

    public static void main (String[]args)
    throws java.io.IOException  {

        int i;

        System.out.println("Press S to stop.");

        for(i = 0; (char) System.in.read() != 'S'; i++)
            System.out.println("Pass #" + i);

        }
    }
```

When I put the wrong input, the output should be:

```
Pass #0
```

But the actual output are:

```
Pass #0
Pass #1
Pass #2
```

Also if I put the wrong input more than one character, it always gives 2 extra output. Let's just say I put an input ABC (3 character). The output will be:

```
Pass #0
Pass #1
Pass #2
Pass #3
Pass #4
```

Is the problem are on the code? Can anyone explain why and share the solution?

Note: I tried to run the code on Command Prompt and Eclipse. Both have the same output.

TY,

Answer (score 1):

I would assume its because of the carriage return and the line feed characters when you press enter after typing "ABC"